# Error: Domino Document has been deleted

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I have created a document with a XPages via web. When I've tried to save the document I've gotten the next error: (see Image 1) It has a RTF field (CkEditor).[image: Image_1]

I tried to open again via web and then I got the next error (see Image 2)
[image: Image_2]

Finally I tried to open that document via Client Lotus and got the error (see Image 3).
[image: Image_3]

Can you help me please???

Thanks in advance,

Ferran.

Comment: Can you show the source of your XPage? I assume you bound the original richtext field to a simple text edit box which stores just text. That would explain the error in the client as the rich content may exceed the 32k limit of a text field.

Comment: Hi Oliver, and Tks. The field is bounded to RTF. Not always happend. I cannot reproduce the error. I have created new documents and I can save it without problems. Thanks.

Comment: Check if the field has summary try to set the summary to false on the item.
You are probably getting the field as text and not Richtext is some way.
And if summary is tru the you will get the field is to large error